# Some (official or not) upgrade Mvc3 to Mvc5 guide?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

There is a (non-Microsoft) NuGet [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4/) that allows upgrading the Mvc3 to Mvc4.

There is a (Microsoft) [article](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806) that explains how to manually migrate from Mvc3 to Mvc4. We can read from that article, by ex:

> Locate the ProjectTypeGuids element and replace
>   {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401} with
>   {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}.

Now, is there something similar that allows migrating from MVC3 to **MVC5**?

Is there sufficient to migrate first from 3 to 4, and then re-target the framework version (to 4.5) and install the [official MVC nu-get](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an answer that someone suggested, then for a unknow cause removed, I will add this article reference for the question above:

[How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

Comment: Mine is a vb.net project and I don't see this line WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration) in Global.asax or Global.asax.vb.  Isn't there an official "how to" form Microsoft somewhere?  I find it surprising that Microsoft created these incompatible versions without providing a tool to help upgrade.

Comment: I'm also surprised that Microsoft doesn't seem to have any recommendation for people who want to go from MVC3 to MVC5.  a) Either directly to MVC5, or b) through MVC4.

Answer (score 37):

Due to the installation of VS2015 I had to convert my applications from MVC3 on MVC5. I've done this with success :). I hope that the following description will help someone in a similar issue:

**1)** Change .Net Framework to 4.5

```
Project -> Properties -> Application -> Target Framework -> 4.5
```

**2)** Install from Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
```

**3)** There is a line in web.config that is:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
```

Changed it to the version of system.web.webpages.dll in your bin folder:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

**4)** If your project uses the EntityFramework you have to upgrade it to version 5.x or higher and set dll references to

```
....\net45\EntityFramework.dll
....\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

**5)** To solve problems like:

```
Error   CS0104  'Compare' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute' and 'System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute'
```

you can add:

```
using CompareAttribute = System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute;
```

**6)** You will probably have to change additional definitions in the **web.config** and the **Views\web.config** and find and replace text as shown below:

`System.Web.Mvc`, `System.Web.Mvc.*`, `System.Web.Razor`, `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` change from `3.0.0.0` to `5.0.0.0`

`System.Web.WebPages`, `System.Web.WebPages.*` change from `1.0.0.0` to `3.0.0.0`

**7)** Now, optionally, you can do a little overview of MVC views and simplify your code with **[Razor conditional attributes](https://blog.craigtp.co.uk/Post/2013/02/17/Razor%27s_Conditional_Attributes_Bit_Me!)**. There was a breaking change in the way Razor behaves.
*([velsietis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642329/some-official-or-not-upgrade-mvc3-to-mvc5-guide/33720546#comment97195069_33720546) comment)*

That's all :)

Comment: As this is one of the top search results for converting MVC 3 to 5, can I suggest you add this step to your answer:  

**7)** Check through your Views for any usages of boolean (or empty string) values inside html attributes.  There was a breaking change in the way Razor behaves [reference](https://blog.craigtp.co.uk/Post/2013/02/17/Razor%27s_Conditional_Attributes_Bit_Me!)