# How to migrate VS2010 MVC3 project to VS2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

When I try to open an existing solution (to ultimately convert it to later MVC and .NET packages), VS2015 rejects the project:

> The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401

That link is worthless as it takes me to a VS2013 compatibility page.

My goal is to migrate the project from MVC3/.NET4.0 to MVC5/.NET4.5.

I can't target a later MVC or .NET in VS2010.  VS2015 won't open the older project so the solution here won't work [Some (official or not) upgrade Mvc3 to Mvc5 guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642329/some-official-or-not-upgrade-mvc3-to-mvc5-guide)? for changing the properties of the project since the project won't open.

Answer (score 1):

Mvc3 is not supported after VS2010.Iuse VS2010SP1.
You may make it work but it will bite you in the end.
You have to choose the VS version and the corresponding Mvc version

Answer (score 0):

I went into the csproj file manually and switched the ProjectTypeGuid to that of an MVC4 project: E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47. Then VS2015 was able to open the project and it upgraded it to MVC5 guid correctly.